# Displaying image with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, camera

I am trying to display an image in #smallImage.

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function capturePhotoWithData() {
   var options = {
       quality: 50
   };
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

alert(imageData) is showing me an tmp file path to the image.

```
<img style="display:none;" id="smallImage" src="" />
```

Does not display the image. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the right options when calling the camera. Specially, you need to peek the right *destinationType* parameter. More details are here:
[Camera plugin definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/cordova/plugins/Camera.d.ts)